# Is this use of JavaScript prototype functions for attaching event listeners going to meet design goals?

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, event-handling, prototypal-class-design

Please provide a sanity check on my below JavaScript pattern to be used for a custom edit control. The goals are:

- Centralized code
- Avoid name collisions
- Minimize memory use (putting functions on the prototype chain to accomplish?)
- Ease of use for other developers

My specific question is, are there any "gotchas" in below pattern that I may have overlooked or anything that I'm doing that is just plain wrong?

```
var CustomEditor = function (id) {
    'use strict';
    var evnt = null,
        funct = null;
    this.id = id;
    this.init();
};

CustomEditor.prototype.onCustomBlur = function () {
    'use strict';
    // alert("blur event handler");
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
    this.style.color = "#f00";
};

CustomEditor.prototype.onCustomKeyPress = function () {
    'use strict';
    // alert("keypress event handler");
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    this.style.color = "#ff0";
};

CustomEditor.prototype.onCustomFocus = function () {
    'use strict';
    // alert("focus event handler");
    this.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
    this.style.color = "#0ff";
};

CustomEditor.prototype.addEvent = function () {
    'use strict';
    var element = document.getElementById(this.id);
    // old IE work around
    if (element.attachEvent) {
        return element.attachEvent('on' + this.evnt, this.funct);
    }
    return element.addEventListener(this.evnt, this.funct, false);
};

CustomEditor.prototype.init = function () {
    'use strict';
    // initialize a custom editor
    this.evnt = 'blur';
    this.funct = this.onCustomBlur;
    this.addEvent();

    this.evnt = 'keypress';
    this.funct = this.onCustomKeyPress;
    this.addEvent();

    this.evnt = 'focus';
    this.funct = this.onCustomFocus;
    this.addEvent();
};
```

This code will be JavaScript code in the HTML page to allocate and initialize:

```
new CustomEditor('myInput1');
new CustomEditor('myInput2');
new CustomEditor('myInput3');
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0jzr6h08/3/) to try this pattern or fork as needed to correct.

Comment: Are you opposed to using a framework for this functionality or do you just want a code review?  You might want to check out http://canjs.com/docs/can.Control it does what you are doing in a pretty generic way and has community support.

Comment: @pllee, thanks for the heads up on can.Control. I'm asking for this review to improve my understanding of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me; but I think the `this.evnt` & `this.funct` abstractions are unnecessary. Would always promote readable properties over shorthand (funct -> function etc), and I think that you should change the `addEvent` method to accept parameters. You can then clean up the code like so:

```
var CustomEditor = function(id) {
    'use strict';
    this.id = id;
    this.init();
};

CustomEditor.prototype.addEvent = function(event, callback) {
    'use strict';
    var element = document.getElementById(this.id);
    // old IE work around
    if (element.attachEvent) {
        return element.attachEvent('on' + event, callback);
    }
    return element.addEventListener(event, callback, false);
};

CustomEditor.prototype.init = function() {
    'use strict';
    this.addEvent('blur', this.onCustomBlur);
    this.addEvent('keypress', this.onCustomKeyPress);
    this.addEvent('focus', this.onCustomFocus);
};
```

See [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0jzr6h08/4/).

Comment: FYI, this pattern is not working with IE10. The events fire, but the this.style.XXX fail due to them being NULL.

Comment: Instead of ataching the id to the object. I would actually cache the DOM look up. this is the part that is really heavy. So instead of calling document.getElementById everytime. I would have the construct accept an element.

Comment: Yeah, `this.style.XXX` is null makes sense; after all given your code you would need to look up the element in the DOM from the cached `this.id`. So... `onCustomFocus` for example should probably look like: `function () { var el = document.getElementById(this.id); el.style.backgroundColor = "#000"; el.style.color = "#0ff"; };`. Better yet would be to cache the look up as per Pinoniq's comment. So that instead of having `this.id = id` you could do `this.element = document.getElementById(id)`. Hope this helps.

Comment: The IE 10 issue I've fixed. I'll post an update later, but basically, the logic test in the `addEvent()` method has to be flipped. However, what I did not realize when I posted the question is that I do not have access to the `CustomEditor` variables from within the event listeners. The issue is `this` references the `input` not `CustomEditor`. I've tried to use `bind()` but I've not gotten it to work. How do I give access to `CustomEditor` variables from the event handler methods?

Comment: You can try `this.addEvent('focus', this.onCustomFocus.bind(this));` - or if using underscore/lodash `this.addEvent('focus', _.bind(this.onCustomFocus, this));`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind